# GAE load data into datastore without using CSV

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've used bulkloader.Loader to load stuff into the GAE dev and live datastore, but my next thing to to create objects from non-CSV data and push it into the datastore.

So say my object is something like:

```
class CainEvent(db.Model):   
    name =db.StringProperty(required=True)  
    birthdate = db.DateProperty()
```

Can anyone give me a simple example on how to do this please?

Comment: What does your input data look like?  You just say it's not CSV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an extremely simplified example of what we're doing to use the bulkloader to load JSON data instead of CSV data:

```
class JSONLoader(bulkloader.Loader):
    def generate_records(self, filename):
        for item in json.load(open(filename)):
            yield item['fields']
```

In this example, I'm assuming a JSON format that looks something like

```
[
    {
        "fields": [
            "a", 
            "b", 
            "c", 
            "d"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "fields": [
            "e", 
            "f", 
            "g", 
            "h"
        ]
    }
]
```

which is oversimplified.

Basically, all you have to do is create a subclass of bulkloader.Loader and implement (at a minimum) the `generate_records` method, which should yield lists of strings.  This same strategy would work for loading data from XML files or ROT13-encrypted files or whatever.

Note that the list of strings yielded by the `generate_records` method must match up (in length and order) with the "properties" list you provide when you initialize the loader (ie, the second argument to the `AlbumLoader.__init__` method in [this example](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Creating_Loader_Classes)).

This approach actually provides a lot of flexibility:  We're overriding the `__init__` method on our `JSONLoader` implementation and automatically determining the `kind` of model we're loading and its list of properties to provide to the `bulkloader.Loader` parent class.

Answer (score 0):

You may find [this post](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Advanced-Bulk-Loading-part-3-Alternate-datasources) useful - it details how to load data direct from an RDBMS, but applies equally to loading from any other source.